# How to only check out parts of a repo in a job in a CircleCI workflow?

Tags: git, performance, continuous-integration, circleci

I want to only check out parts of a repo in a job in a CircleCI workflow. 
Is this possible?

Let's say I'm working on a monorepo project that looks like this

```
- project_dir
  - frontend_dir
  - backend_dir
```

I'm using CircleCI to do continuous integration of my code. To improve the speed of my iterations I've broken down the CI step into [Workflows](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/). The config.yml looks like this (duplicating the jobs for simplicity)

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  "frontend":
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install deps and build
          command: |
            cd frontend
            yarn install
            yarn build
  "backend":
        docker:
          - image: circleci/node:7.10
        steps:
          - checkout
          - run:
              name: Install deps and build
              command: |
                cd backend
                yarn install
                yarn build

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - "frontend"
      - "backend"
```

If understand things correctly these jobs would both check out everything. Is there some way to only have CircleCI check out the `frontend_dir` in the `frontend` job? It feels unnecessary to do everything multiple times.

Or does CircleCI only check out once anyway?

Answer (score -1):

That's not how Git works, which is what we're using to retrieve the code from GitHub/Bitbucket.

You're correct that everything will be checked out. You can change the `working_dir` per job to be in the correct project directory for that job.

`working_dir` would be at the same indention level as `steps`.

- Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI